# Backup a programming directory

Tags: linux

I have a directory with many compiled C programs that I would like to back up. Right now they are named `program.out` but I would like to change this to just `program`.

Would it still be possible to exclude these? Also, what sort of regex would I use to quickly rename them all?

Comment: If you are just trying to rename some files, how is the script you posted relevant? I don't see any mention of `program.out` in the script anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For backing up your code use git or other version control software.
On the internet you got lot of choices to name some: github, bitbucket.

In git you got file .gitignore if you add there *.out then it wont be transfered to the repository

Comment: I feel embarrassed putting all of my "baby's first C" code on the internet.

Comment: Gitlab and bitbucket got private repos. On the other hand if you put it where public eye can see it your code will get better as you will tend to be better coder. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too clear on your first question. If you want to rename `program.out` to `program` then just run:

```
mv program{.out,}
```

---

For the second question, assuming I wanted to obtain a list of files in `/etc` with a suffix:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls /etc > /tmp/etcfiles
while read line
do
   if [[ $line =~ \..+ ]]; then
      echo $line
   fi
done < /tmp/etcfiles
```

You can adjust the above as required.

- `\.` matches a literal period.
- `.` matches any character following the period.
- `+` says that at least one character must follow the initial period. So this will match `test.c`, but not `test.` If you want to match `test.` as well, then change the `+` to a `*`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash as a shell, this is a simple task for a shell pipeline.

```
ls | grep '\.out$' | while read file; do echo mv "$file" "${file%.*}"; done
```

`ls` produces a list of files in the directory.

`grep '\.out$'` extracts the filenames that end in .out and discards the rest.

`while read file` reads the filenames one at a time.

`echo mv "$file" "${file%.*}"` displays but does not run a mv command that would rename each file to a version without its extension.  The `${file%.*}` business is bash syntax for stripping off a file extension.  When you're satisfied that the pipeline would do what you wanted if it were run for real, remove the `echo` part and let it run for real.

```
ls | grep '\.out$' | while read file; do mv "$file" "${file%.*}"; done
```

Comment: But how do I make a script ignore these files once they don't have the .out extension?

Comment: Use the `test` command.  `test -x` succeeds if a file's permissions have the execute bit set.

Comment: That seems a bit hard... could you maybe help me with writing that?

So I have t test if it is executable...and if it isn't, copy it.

Comment: Can you please help me? I thought I ahd the gist of it, but now it just isn't working.